# Why do I keep running into "EOFError: EOF when reading file" on my python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep running into `EOFError: EOF when reading a line` on my program for my Python homework. I've gotten this whole program running when I go to execute it, it's fully interactive and works as intended. But when I go to check my work against the code check, it says that:

```py
Enter Cost per ice cream serving: Employee labor rate (per hour): 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "shop.py", line 11, in <module>
    labor_rate=float(input("Employee labor rate (per hour): "))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line.
```

This is my full code of my program

```
cost_per_ice_cream_serving=float(input("Enter Cost per ice cream serving: "))
labor_rate=float(input("Employee labor rate (per hour): "))
shop_rental=float(input("Shop rental (per month): "))
utilities=float(input("Utilities (per month): "))
advertising=float(input("Advertising (per month): "))
selling_price=float(input("Selling price (each): "))
serve_sold_per_month=float(input("Ice cream servings sold per month: "))

monthly_expenses = 0
income = 0
profit = 0

print("\n")

menu = f"\nExpenses:\n\
1. Cost per serving:{cost_per_ice_cream_serving}\n\
2. Labor rate per hour:{labor_rate}\n\
3. Shop rental per month:{shop_rental}\n\
4. Utilities per month:{utilities}\n\
5. Advertising budget per month:{advertising}\n\
\n\
Income:\n\
6. Selling price (each):{selling_price}\n\
7. Servings sold per month:{serve_sold_per_month}\n\
\n\
Analysis:\n\
8. Profit/Loss Calculation\n\
9. 'What If' analysis with 10% variance\n\
10. Find Break-Even\n"

while True:
print(menu)
selection = int(input("Enter Selection (0 to Exit): "))

if selection == 0:
    break
elif selection == 1:
    cost_per_ice_cream_serving = float(input("Enter new value for Cost per ice cream serving: "))
elif selection == 2:
    labor_rate = float(input("Enter new value for Labor rate per hour: "))
elif selection == 3:
    shop_rental = float(input("Enter new value for Shop rental per month:: "))
elif selection == 4:
    utilities = float(input("Enter new value for Utilities per month: "))
elif selection == 5:
    advertising = float(input("Enter new value for Advertising budget per month: "))
elif selection == 6:
    selling_price = float(input("Enter new value for Selling price (each): "))
elif selection == 7:
    serve_sold_per_month = float(input("Enter new value for Servings sold per month: "))
elif selection == 8:
    ice_cream_cost_per_month = cost_per_ice_cream_serving * serve_sold_per_month
    WORKING_HOURS = 8
    NUM_OF_WORKING_DAYS = 24
    employee_salary = labor_rate * WORKING_HOURS * NUM_OF_WORKING_DAYS
    monthly_expenses = ice_cream_cost_per_month + employee_salary + shop_rental + \
                       utilities + advertising
    income = selling_price * serve_sold_per_month
    profit = round((income - monthly_expenses), 2)
    profit_per_serving = round(profit / serve_sold_per_month, 2)

    print(f"The Ice Cream Shop will have a monthly profit/loss of {profit} or {profit_per_serving} per serving.")
elif selection == 9:
    print("Varying the Expenses +/-10%:")
    for percent in range(-10, 10, 2):
        expense_varied = monthly_expenses + monthly_expenses * (percent / 100)
        profit_varied = round((income - expense_varied), 2)
        print(f"Percent:  {percent} Expenses:  {expense_varied} Profit/Loss:  {profit_varied}")
    print("Varying the Income +/-10%:")
    for percent in range(-10, 10, 2):
        income_varied = income + income * (percent / 100)
        profit_varied = round((income_varied - monthly_expenses), 2)
        print(f"Percent:  {percent} Expenses:  {monthly_expenses} Profit/Loss:  {profit_varied}")

elif selection == 10:
    even_price = round(monthly_expenses / serve_sold_per_month, 2)
    print(f"Break-Even occurs with a selling price of: {even_price}")

else:
    print("Invalid input!")
```

Comment: "when I go to check my work against the code check" **What exactly does this mean?** What steps do you take in order to do this? For example, is your code saved into a file and then uploaded to some web site? Do you run a local program on your computer? Something else? Also: can you [reproduce the problem with a shorter version of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: "my program for my python homework" Does the assignment **say** that you're supposed to get input by using `input`? Or does it say that the input will be supplied from a file? Or something else?

Comment: `input` failed because the program's `stdin` has been closed. Whatever runs your test is supplying data in a different way than you think. You need to figure out what that tool does. One trick is to add a line at the top of your file `input sys;print(sys.stdin.read())` to see what is actually being passed in.

Comment: I'm working on Cengage's Mindtap platform, which I type my code up in, and has a virtual terminal next to it to check functionally.  They have these steps to check and make sure your code is working properly.  My task was to create a text based interactive menu for a ice cream business.  Every check I run fails due to these EOF errors, that all are from the first few lines in code where I set up the user inputs.

Comment: @tdelaney maybe you mean `import sys`?

Comment: @studentmain - oops, messed that up.  `import sys;print(sys.stdin.read())`

Comment: this is just my suspicion - and i have no evidence that this is true, maybe there is a problem with the submission platform online, please add additional empty lines at the end of your homework, and try to submit - maybe it might work